# Bigtop Hbase tables disappeared after PC restart

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, bigtop

I installed Bigtop 0.7.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I started without any problem the master server with:

```
sudo hbase master start
```

I was able to connect with hbase shell and create a table.

After I restarted the PC, I saw that table is not there anymore.

I read that the problem is that it stores tables in /tmp which is cleared after restart, so I tried to change the configuration hbase-site.xml to set another folder.

the default hbase-site.xml was:

```
<configuration/>
```

(No properties defined)

When I wrote in hbase-site.xml, then I tried to start the hbase master again and I recieved Zookeeper client exception not possible to connect to server.

Can you please give me some advice on how to configure this right or if there is maybe some other problem that I'm not aware of?

**EDIT** (from the comments):

My hbase-site.xml is:

```
<configuration>
  <!--property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file://app/hadoop/tmp/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <property-->
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Ivo and welcome to stackoverflow. I reformatted your question a bit, hoping it will get better answers that way. Could you include the modified version of `hbase-site.xml` and the output of `ls -l` with the directory that the tables are stored in? Those details should help further improve answers.

Comment: Hi CMW ;).My hbase-site.xml is:<configuration>
  <!--property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file://app/hadoop/tmp/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>

 <property-->
</configuration>

Comment: please edit your additional information into your question (check for formatting, too)